# Workflow: Create List Item String to Lookup

Tags: designer-workflow, lookup-column

Hi I am using SharePoint Online. I am trying to create a list item (list is called Tasks) in SPD workflow. I am trying to set a lookup column in the Tasks list using a calculated column (string value) from the current item. I understand that the lookup column in the Tasks list i am trying to create the item uses an ID and not the display string of the column but I am struggling to make this work.

I have created an Integer variable varName and set this to Current item:Name (the calculated string value column) As Integer.

I have set the field in Tasks List to Value = Variable: varName (As Integer)

I think i am missing some fundamental understanding on handling string & lookup columns in workflow.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by using a setting a workflow Integer variable to current item ID and then using this variable as the value in the create item. Not sure why the solution posted above didnt work for me but I have a solution now.

Answer (score 1):

No need to define a variable , you can set a lookup field as the following

[image]

Where Users is the list of lookup field

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. i have tried to set the item based on your instructions but it is still not creating for me. Can you see any errors in my latest screenshot posted above?